# Python 2.7 : unknown url type: urllib2 - BeautifulSoup

Tags: string, python-2.7, url, beautifulsoup, urllib2

## import libraries

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

## new libraries:

```
import csv
import requests 
import string
```

Defining variables:

```
i = 1
str_i = str(i)
seqPrefix = 'seq_'
seq_1 = str('https://anyaddress.com/')
quote_page = seqPrefix + str_i
```

#Then, make use of the Python urllib2 to get the HTML page of the url declared.

```
# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)  


#Finally, parse the page into BeautifulSoup format so we can use BeautifulSoup to work on it.

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

As a result, all is fine...except that:

ERROR MESSAGE:

page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 423, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: seq_1

Why?

txs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the local variable dictionary vars()

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(vars()[quote_page])
```

The way you had it it was trying to open the URL using the string "seq_1" as the URL not the value of the seq_1 variable which is a valid URL.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to concat `seq_1` & `str_i`

**Ex:**

```
seq_1 = str('https://anyaddress.com/')
quote_page = seq_1 + str_i
```

**Output:**

```
https://anyaddress.com/1
```